# Different results output exec command in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, exec

Code tested out of Laravel and work

```
$process = 'nginx';
$pids  = exec('ps aux|grep "'.$process.'" |grep -v grep');
var_dump($pids) 

Exit->  string(86) "www-data  1197  0.0  0.0 125800  3552 ?        S    13:01   0:00 nginx: worker process"
```

This code is on one command of laravel. If execute my command, when 
On localhost on MacosX with Valet (php 7.1) work fine. $pids is a string with content if proccess is running catch this code, result is fine. Get a string with ps lines.

On server with PHP 7.0 alltimes, return empty string ""

Comment: it can have different settings. Is `exec('ps aux')` empty too?

Comment: This is a really stupid question, but it needs to be asked: are you running nginx on your server as well?

Comment: @JoelHinz `nginx`it's only used for proof. On server there're running nginx server, and if there a nginx server there're process with nginx catch by grep.